# Debugging a Simple IF Statement in PHP

Tags: php, database, session, if-statement, while-loop

Code

DOES NOT WORK --

```
$u = $_SESSION['username'];
while($responseanswer=mysqli_fetch_array($rquery)){

if($responseanswer['onuser']=='$u'&&$responseanswer['response']=='')
{
    echo "awesome";
}
}
```

WORKS

```
$u = $_SESSION['username'];
    while($responseanswer=mysqli_fetch_array($rquery)){

    if($responseanswer['onuser']&&$responseanswer['response']=='')
    {
        echo "awesome";
    }
    }
```

How do I resolve this? $u is perfectly fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single quotes are not interpolated for variables inside them.  This should work:

```
if($responseanswer['onuser']==$u && $responseanswer['response']=='')
```

But one thing to note, I'd *highly* suggest that you format your cod ebetter.  Include spaces where appropriate, and always indent for scope.  So that code would become:

```
$u = $_SESSION['username'];
while ($responseanswer=mysqli_fetch_array($rquery)) {
    if ($responseanswer['onuser'] == $u && $responseanswer['response'] == '') {
        echo "awesome";
    }
}
```

Comment: sure..i'll do that...also is it correct for security purposes the way I am using sessions?

Comment: @sarthak: without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, it's hard to say if what you're doing makes sense from a security standpoint...

Answer (score 2):

I believe

```
$responseanswer['onuser']=='$u'
```

should be

```
$responseanswer['onuser']==$u
```

without the single quotes around `$u`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a big difference between `'` and `"`.

Try this:

```
$a = "foo";
echo('$a' . " $a"); // You'll get: $a foo
```

Anyway, don't put your variables into strings just to compare them. Just use `$responseanswer['onuser']==$u`.

Good luck!